# Shorthand IF doesn't work. Why?

Tags: php

I'm want to shorten the following if statement:

```
 function is_string_length_correct( $string, $min, $max = 0 ) {
    if (is_string($string)) {
        $l = mb_strlen($string);
        if ($max != 0) {
            return ($l >= $min && $l <= $max);
        } else {
            return ($l >= $min);
        }
    }
  }
```

Can someone explain me why the followin shorthand if doesn't work?

```
function is_string_length_correct( $string, $min, $max = 0 ) {
    if (is_string($string)) {
        $l = mb_strlen($string);
        return ($max != 0) ? ($l >= $min && $l <= $max) : ($l >= $min);
    }
 }
```

Thank you

Comment: Is the full version working? Coz short version is right.

Comment: Try to dump $l, $min and $max.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  Crashing?  Returns the wrong result under what specific conditions?  As it stands this won't repro.

Comment: @PraveenKumar The full version works.

Comment: I've tried lots of different combinations of `$l`, `$max`, and `$min` and can't get them to return different results.

Comment: @djechlin: It returns nothing.

Comment: By nothing do you mean null?  A crash?  For what values of max, l, and min does it return "nothing"?

Comment: Guys, I've posted the full code

Comment: No you haven't.  You need to post the calling code as well because as it stands this is not in error.

Comment: How did you determine that it "returned nothing"? PHP doesn't have a "nothing". If you use `echo` or `print_r()`, they display `false` as an empty string; you should use `var_dump()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is fine. The problem likely lies with the value of `$max` at runtime. `0` is falsy, so you are comparing it to the integer zero, it should be `($max !== 0)`.

Comment: Wouldn't that apply to both versions?

Comment: I understand the difference of strict equality. But I'm failing to see when this is the problem.

Comment: Man you've found the solution!
I don't know why, but the full version works also without the double equal sign; the shorthand version don't.

Comment: I really don't see how this can be the fix. Can you provide example inputs to the function where it makes a difference?

Answer (score 1):

You can also write it only with boolean operators:

```
return $l >= $min && ($l <= $max || $max == 0);
```

Comment: + Nice alternative by condensing the logic.